# Using Oracle Application Express in Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cloud, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created an instance on Database Cloud Service on Oracle Cloud with Oracle 11g. I followed the steps mentioned in the documentation to create a database service called "Test-11g-service".

https://cloud.oracle.com/developer/dbcs-schema

[image: Select Oracle apex console]

When I select the Oracle APEX console like above, it gives this error

[image]

What could be the reason for it, please help me out here?

Answer (score 4):

To get this working, open a terminal session in your VM

```
cd /u01/app/oracle/product/glassfish3/bin

./asadmin set 'configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.ssl3-tls-ciphers=+TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,+TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'

./asadmin set 'configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.sec-admin-listener.ssl.ssl3-tls-ciphers=+TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,+TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'
```

Then you'll need to restart glassfish using the Database as a Service (DBaaS) command-line tools.

Comment: Hi, i SSH the server using putty, but it asking server username and password when executing these commands, as i remember when creating the database service i only gave the SYS password ?

Comment: those are database accounts, you need to use the OS level accounts

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that Chrome does not let you go into websites with weak certificates, it was introduced to remedy the logjam issue.

Jeff's solution is implemented on the server, you can tell Chrome to accept it. This is more for solving it to websites you trust where you cannot yourself remedy the real problem.

Windows

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013

Mac

> open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args
>   --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013